How to launch a specific version of firefox with Selenium
Geckodriver 0.35.0 does not seems to support the latest Firefox as I get the error message:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line 

So I want to tell my Selenium automation to launch the previous version supported there (something from https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html).
How can I do this?

Here you can find the previous versions of Firefox: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
You can install the installer or extract the zip/tarball.
Then you can indicate the binary with this code:
Python
geckodriver_path = "/path/to/geckodriver"

firefox_binary_path = "/path/to/firefox/binary"

options = Options()
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path

service = Service(geckodriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

Java:
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");

FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/path/to/firefox/binary"));

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);


Solution :

Use DriverManager() So you do not need to check & handle the dependancies manually
Example : adds GeckoDriverManager import

from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


Instantiates the WebDriver

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

